# Could not determine java version from '15.0.1'

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I try to upload my test package firebase App Distribution by using
`./gradlew assembleAlphaDebug appDistributionUploadAlphaDebug` code snippet through android studio terminal, 5 days before I updated my java version and then I have started getting this error. I have not come across any solution until now.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine java version from '15.0.1'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Since JDK 9 the version string format [changed](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223).

Comment: You need to use a Gradle version which is compatible with Java 15. I believe the Gradle release which added support for Java 15 is [Gradle 6.7](https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/release-notes.html).

Comment: Or don't use Java 15.

Comment: Can you upgrade to gradle 2.4.1 and see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac, follow these steps:

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
Add in JAVA_HOME path there
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/bdc/opt/jdk
Save :wq
Execute source ~/.bash-profile
```

Once done do `echo $JAVA_Home`
and try your next steps.